# Best option to set ``nthreads`` in the Dask worker

Tags: python, kubernetes, dask

I will run mutultiples executions of an algorithm on Kubernetes with [Dask KubeCluster](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/kubecluster.html). I want a worker to run one and only one algorithm, so I'm confused with `nthreads` argument passed to the dask-worker at initialization.

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: MyName
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: MyFunnyDockerImage
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    args: [dask-worker, --nthreads, '4', --no-dashboard, --memory-limit, 8GB, --death-timeout, '60']
    name: execslotting

    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: 8G
      requests:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: 8G

  imagePullSecrets: 
    - name: acr-secret
```

When I set `--nthreads=4` am I leaving the possibility that 4 executions of my algorithm will be run in that worker?

Answer (score 2):

The `nthreads` argument speciefies the number of threads on the host machine or pod that the dask worker process can use for running computations. See the [Dask worker docs here](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#thread-pool).

When you set `--nthreads=4` you're telling Dask that the worker process can use 4 threads, regardless of how many threads are available on that pod. If for example your pod has 8 threads available Dask would only use half of those if you specify `--nthreads=4`.

Also see the [Kubernetes docs on CPU units](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#cpu-units) for a more detailed explanation of how vCPU units relate to threads in Kubernetes.

If you do not specify `nthreads`, then Dask will set a sane default using as many threads as there are CPU cores available on your machine, which seems to match the way Kubernetes handles multithreading (1 vCPU = 1 Hyperthread).

In your example, you have set `resources.requests.cpu=4` which means that pod will have 4 threads available for use. So setting `--nthreads=4` will allow the Dask worker process to make full use of that pods resources. Although I believe not setting `nthreads` will achieve the same result.

Comment: Note that you can have as many threads as you like, even more than CPUs allocated, but kubernetes will decide how many can run at once - so there is usually no benefit to over-subscribing.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but how do I make sure that in that pod runs one and only algorithm?

Comment: Can you share some more information on what algorithm you’re trying to run and what library you’re using? Can you share a code snippet?